# Extracting a word document attatchment from an IBM notes database

Tags: java, lotus-domino, lotus-notes

I am developing a Java Application which will connect to an IBM notes database and extract the attachment (which will be a word document) from a given database entry. The word document then needs to be saved to the local disk. I have read through similar situations on here but I cant seem to get any further than confirming there is an embedded file within that document, I cant seem to access it. The code I have so far is:

```
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Vector;
import lotus.domino.*;
import lotus.domino.cso.RichTextItem;

public class notesRetrieval extends NotesThread
{   
public void runNotes()
    {
    try
    {
        Session s = NotesFactory.createSessionWithFullAccess("testpassword");
        Database db = s.getDatabase("Server1", "dev/test.nsf", false);
        View materialview = db.getView("MaterialNumberLU");
        Document doc = materialview.getDocumentByKey("3005");
        System.out.print(doc.hasEmbedded());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

My hasEmbedded test statement returns **true** so I know there is an attatchment. If it is of any benefit, the word document on this particular notes entry is named "C4-P0007-BRS.doc". I have had play about with getAttachment(), getEmbeddedObjects(), and getFirstItem() but no avail. Any help much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attachments usually are embedded in Richtext- items (most of the time). In memos the name of this item is "Body". Try the methods of Richtextitem to get the attachment. Here is an example from the designer help:

```
RichTextItem body = (RichTextItem)doc.getFirstItem("Body");
    Vector v = body.getEmbeddedObjects();
    Enumeration e = v.elements();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
      EmbeddedObject eo = (EmbeddedObject)e.nextElement();
      if (eo.getType() == EmbeddedObject.EMBED_ATTACHMENT) {
        eo.extractFile("c:\\extracts\\" + eo.getSource());
        }
    }
```

There is another possibility to extract embedded objects directly from the document, but therefor you need the name of the attachment. You can get all Attachmentnames using the "Evaluate"- statement:

```
Vector attachmentNames = session.evaluate("@AttachmentNames", doc);
Enumeration e = attachmentNames.elements();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
        String attachmentName = e.nextElement();
        EmbeddedObject eo = doc.getAttachment( attachmentName );
        if (eo.getType() == EmbeddedObject.EMBED_ATTACHMENT) {
            eo.extractFile("c:\\extracts\\" + eo.getSource());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, im running the top code you gave me but it seems to throw an error. java.lang.ClassCastException: lotus.domino.local.RichTextItem cannot be cast to lotus.domino.cso.RichTextItem

Comment: Why did you import "lotus.domino.cso.RichTextItem"? There is the error... You don't even need that import...

Comment: The second solution you provided has solved the problem. File is now extracting. Thanks very much!

Comment: When i am using this code  RichTextItem body = (RichTextItem)doc.getFirstItem("Body"); i am getting body as null . dont know why?

Comment: Please open a new question for this and write your complete code, this is not the place to help you